# Reverse Http Post operation from Server to Mobile devices

Tags: mobile, push

Well, majority of the HTTP Post and Get operations are from device to the server.  The server port listening to the request and send response accordingly.

Now What if doing in reverse, the Server pushing the data out to devices. The device is listening on its port and The server would use the POST operations to push the data.

Is there an example, that the device handle this type of PUSH, or reverse HTTP POST operation?

Answer (score 0):

Their are a number of ways to accomplish this. This is generally referred to as push. The following may help to get you started:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push

There are a number of solutions available to do this. The one I'm most familiar with is NGiNX's [HTTP push module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/). The site provides some [example code](http://pushmodule.slact.net/js/dumbchat.js) to get you started.

Comment: Hi , I am looking for working example of HTTP server push for Iphone or Android side. How it can accept that push from the server.